# Any relationship between " tc " command and /user/src/kernel-source/net/sched in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, algorithm, networking, linux-kernel, qos

I want to know some basic of Traffic Control in the Linux kernel . I downloaded Linux kernel source code and i can see scheduling algorithms are present in

```
 /user/src/kernel-source/net/sched
```

After that i tried about setting Queuing discipline using `TC command` in Linux .I tried to check the default queuing mechanism  using following tc command

```
tc qdisc show
```

This is working fine . I can see the `default FIFO queuing` . Now i want to add `CBQ` discipline to add with `TC` command . I can add with tc command

```
tc qdisc [add | del | replace | change] cbq
```

Now i have a doubt , when i run this command , the scheduler will change the algorithm from `FIFO to CBQ` in `/user/src/kernel-source/net/sched` ? or any relationship between the `/user/src/kernel-source/net/sched` algorithms with `Tc` command ? if not , then how can i see the Tc command Linux source code ?